# Printing unique strings in a tuple of 2-tuples

Tags: python

For a given tuple of tuples, I want to print the unique items that occur in the first position of each tuple, for the following `rows`, they would be: `python, PHP, html`

This is what I tried:

```
rows = (('python', 'kivy'), ('python', 'tkinter'),("python","wxpython"),
('PHP', 'bootstrap'),('html', 'ajax'),('html', 'css'))

for row in rows:
    if row[0] not in rows:
       print(row[0])
```

Comment: if it is only one should be printed and you with `python` which is three one should be printed.

Comment: So if you want to print it if _"it exists more than only one"_ and if _"it exists one_" i.e. you want to print it regardless if it exists once or multiple times?

Comment: Is the _"exists more than one"_ criteria only applicable to the first tuple element?

Comment: @zwer yes that what i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you just want to print every occurrence of the first item regardless of repetitions, and print it only once? To do so, you can use a `set`:

```
print(", ".join(set(e[0] for e in rows)))
# python, html, PHP
```

If you need to keep the order, then it's a bit more difficult - you'll have to use a temporary set to weed out the duplicates:

```
seen = set()  # temp set
print(", ".join(l for l, p in rows if l not in seen and not seen.add(l)))
# python, PHP, html
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just take all the first items and put them in a set? And then print the set?

```
my_set = set(item[0] for item in rows)
print(my_set)  # {'python', 'html', 'PHP'}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use a list ( as checklist )

```
rows = (('python', 'kivy'), ('python', 'tkinter'),("python","wxpython"),('PHP', 'bootstrap'),('html', 'ajax'),('html', 'css') )

lista=[]
for i in rows:
    if i[0] not in lista: 
        lista.append(i[0])
        print(i[0])
```

or

```
rows = (('python', 'kivy'), ('python', 'tkinter'),("python","wxpython"),('PHP', 'bootstrap'),('html', 'ajax'),('html', 'css') )

lista=[]    
[lista.append(i[0]) for i in rows if i[0] not in lista]
for i in lista: print(i)
```

Comment: That's incredibly inefficient (`O(n²)`).